docker faild to run mysql - Error response from daemon: Container f50e... is not running
After install mysql by
docker run -d `
    --network todo-app --network-alias mysql `
    -v todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql `
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abcdef `
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=app `
    mysql:8.0

Step 1:
I am trying to run mysql by
docker exec -it f50ed31561a4 mysql -p

Step 2:
Docker- Dahsboard- Mysql- RUN

A little green light display RUNNING text and with in 1 seconds it disappear
Full error
docker exec -it f50ed31561a4 mysql -p
Error response from daemon: Container f50ed31561a4567cd6104267d5ac774fc358ef1544f3427fcc1d9e77d082526b is not running

I uninstall/re-install mysql & docker desktop but the problem is the same
It can't run at all

What is your docker desktop version

Is there any output in the container logs (docker logs f50ed31561a4)?  (Consider using docker run --name instead of --network-alias, which will let you use the name in other docker commands as well as for connectivity between containers.)

@DavidMaze please check the
logs here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JMLmGyvmCEzEIMjkfNeICIF-aOg7dVUAK7TCDbItl5A/edit

@say, Version: Docker Desktop Installer_2.3.0.2(45183)

What's your os?

windows 10 enterprise

Docker desktop 3.4.0 solve the problem
Note: must remove previous all instance of docker
